# Запуск и взаимодействие с внешним приложением

Tags: c#, winapi, steam

Задача: автоматический вход на аккаунт Steam

Как взаимодействовать с процессом, если по имени его не находит а ClassName при каждом запуске меняется?

+еще и хендл дается только окну, все внутренние элементы его не получают (как вебсайты)

Запускаю через Process.Start();

Я не прошу готовый код, хотя бы направление дайте куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы запускаете именно через `Process.Start()` - нестатическую версию метода без параметров - то объект process и будет представлять ваш процесс.

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";    
// ...
process.Start();
// и дальше используете process.MainWindowHandle и process.Id как вам угодно
```

Comment: Спасибо, наконецто, а то только начал учить, а на MSDN без примеров, и никак не мог понять какие методы имеет класс process